# Prevent Ruby on Rails from sending the session header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, session

How do I prevent Rails from always sending the session header (Set-Cookie). This is a security problem if the application also sends the Cache-Control: public header.

My application touches (but does not modify) the session hash in some/most actions. These pages display no private content so I want them to be cacheable - but Rails always sends the cookie header, no matter if the sent session hash is different from the previous or not.

What I want to achieve is to only send the hash if it is different from the one received from the client. How can you do that? And probably that fix should also go into official Rails release? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Rails only adds the session cookie data to the Set-Cookie header if it has been touched. You might be setting things to the values that they already contain - it's not smart enough to check to see if the data is actually different.

**edit** My response is a little misleading. When you are using the cookie session store, a new cookie is set if the cookie value (after Marshaling) changes.

See `actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb`

Comment: Yeah I already suspected that... Does "touching" in this sense also mean reading from the session hash? +1 for supporting my suspicion

Comment: Reading is okay. Check out CGI::Session::CookieStore#close in actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3 then use this.

`env['rack.session.options'][:skip] = true`

or the equivalent

`request.session_options[:skip] = true`

You can find the documentation for it here http://doc.rubyists.com/rack/Rack/Session/Abstract/ID.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is the crucial line:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :nil_session_store
```

See the [whole post](http://johnpwood.net/2009/09/04/disabling-sessions-in-rails-2-3-4/).

Comment: Hmm well, but I actually need a session store. I just don't want Rails to send the Set-Cookie response header if it does not differ from the hash that the client sent with the corresponding request header.